# print "#{x}" and print x

Tags: ruby

In ruby I am used to print a variable in this way:

```
x = "anything"
print x
```

But many tutorials I have seen do it in this way:

```
x = "anything"
print "#{x}"
```

So what is the difference and why do we use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called string Interpolation. Follow this [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) to learn more about it.

Basically it is more of a convenient way when writing string templates and variables together.

Answer (score 3):

The `#{X}` syntax is using [String Interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation), which means that it will evaluate the expression between the `#{}`. This is very useful if you want your String to contain both variables and fixed parts, like this:

```
result = "19"
p "The result is #{result}"
```

Pay attention that this works only with double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The below code hope would give you quick sense of the use of `print "#{}"`.

```
print class X;def show;p "hi";end;end;X.new.show
"hi"
#=> "hi"
print "#{class X;def show;p "hi";end;end;X.new.show}"
#"hi"
#hi=> nil
```